# Copy every HTML attribute containing a particular string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm looking at a web page with a bunch of pictures on it.  Hundreds. I want to download all these pictures at full resolution in one go.  If I right-click-save-as each picture, it will give me a lower-resolution picture than the highest-res one stored on the server.

However, the full res ones are referenced in the source code of the page when I 'Inspect Element'.  Problem is they are scattered across a bunch of different classes and HTML attributes.  Sometimes they are in the 'href' attribute.  Sometimes in one called 'data-hd'.

Thankfully, each high-res image ends in "_1280.jpg".  What I want is the full filename, which would be, for example, "media.website.com/folderstructurestuffhere/longalphanumericstringhere_1280.jpg"

So my question is:

How do I use Javascript to find every instance of a particular phrase (in this case, "_1280.jpg"), grab the full text/URL from whatever attribute contains that phrase, then write it to the console?

Comment: need the code your working with

Comment: You're using jQuery (good!). So all you have to do is 1) apply a regex, 2) on all <img> elements.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I use Javascript to find every instance of a particular phrase (in this case, "_1280.jpg"),

```
$("img[src*=_1280\\.jpg], img[data-hd*=_1280\\.jpg]")
.each(function() {
  console.log(this.src, this.dataset.hd)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

SUGGESTION:

Why not just use [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/download.html)?

Download the whole page (and everything in it), then simpl6 delete everything but the .jpg files.